# understanding Apache Pig's GROUP A ALL in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-pig, pyspark

I'm still learning big data tools and machine learning. So, I had an example with PIG latin that loads a CSV file and does some grouping and analytics.

```
Y = LOAD '...'
Y_all = GROUP Y_good ALL;
Umax  = FOREACH Y_all GENERATE MAX(Y_all.columnA);
DUMP Umax
```

This gets the maximum value of columnA. Now I'm trying to do the same thing in PySpark. But first, I don't understand the [GROUP ALL](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP) command. I though of using flatMap and reduceByKey.

Any help is appreciated. There must be some way to get the maximum value in a really easy way. Feels like my head is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

That's one solution that I found.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
Y_all.select([max(Y_all.columnA)]).show()
```

But is there a way to achieve that with flatMap/Map and reduceByKey?